# error trying to attach to virtual machine

Tags: java, jvm

I'm trying to attach to a running JVM to debug it using the Virtual Machine class in java. I'm currently have java 8, with jdk1.8.0_11. I have tried to add a manifest to it, with  but to no avail. I'm also importing the tools.jar file from my JDK\libs folder.

My code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import com.sun.tools.attach.AgentInitializationException;
import com.sun.tools.attach.AgentLoadException;
import com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException;
import com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine;
import com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachineDescriptor;

public class loadVM {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "replaceAfterNameFound";
        List <VirtualMachineDescriptor> vms = VirtualMachine.list();
        for (VirtualMachineDescriptor vmd: vms) {
            System.out.println(vmd.displayName());
            if (vmd.displayName().equals(name)) {
                try {
                    VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(vmd.id());
                    String agent = "";
                    vm.loadAgent(agent);
                } catch(AttachNotSupportedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch(AgentLoadException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch(AgentInitializationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a copy of the error I get when running it:

> java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:com.sun.tools.attach.spi.AttachProvider:
>   Provider sun.tools.attach.WindowsAttachProvider could not be
>   instantiated

Thank you guys for all your help!

Comment: The manifest is irrelevant, it only comes to play when a jar should be loaded as agent, but your operation already failed at the preceding `attach` step, so no attempt to load an agent is made. Do I understand you correctly that you are using the same `jdk1.8.0_11` for the tool and the already running JVM?

Comment: Correct, which is why im pondering on the fact im recieving the error itself. Yes im using the tools.jar file located in the jdk\lib\ folder. Im trying to connect to another previously opened JVM, which is running the the same versions.